# Issue Mounting NAS

Tags: 12.04, mount, nfs, nas

I am trying to mount a NAS on one of my servers:

```
htadmin@testing:~$ showmount -e 10.0.0.210
Export list for 10.0.0.210:
/humanresources         
/Web                    
/Usb                    
/Recordings             
/Public                 
/Network Recycle Bin 1  
/Multimedia             
/Download               
/Data
```

Now I try to mount it:

```
sudo mount -o soft,intr,user_name=administrator,password=xxxxxxxx \
,rsize=8192,wsize=8192 10.0.0.210:/Data /mnt/nas
```

And I am presented with the following error message:

```
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
```

Any help here would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: Try without the user_name and password options. I don't think that's how NFS authentication works

Comment: Try adding the filesystem type to the command line: `-t nfs`. nfs is not supported by the normal mount command.

Comment: I don't think NFS supports giving a username/password. The access control is done on the server, which specifies which IP addresses to allow mounting an exported directory

Comment: Did you created `/mnt/nas` directory? all the directories you will be using you need to create before, like: `sudo mkdir /mnt/nas`

Comment: could also be a problem with NFS version - ubuntu default is NFSv4 as far as I know, and some NASes (Synology, looking at you!) only support NFS3. I remember having problems with that, and falling back to samba as a consequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:
sudo mount -t cifs //10.0.0.210/data -o username=xxxx,password=xxxx,rw,nounix,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755 /mnt/nas

Comment: aha, so it's not an NFS mount after all. that explains why you need username/password. makes sense now that I know it's samba/cifs

Answer (score 3):

I'd try issuing the command eliding options one by one, this way finding which one is incorrect; that would be a step forward in finding out the actual problem.